# Identify single/multiple food elements inside a string (user input)

Tags: php, mysql, regex, full-text-search

This is my first post after trying to find a solution to my question without luck.

I'll appreciate if you can help me :)

I'm trying to develope a solution were the user input what they have eaten for breakfast in a texbox, so lets say "an orange with toast bread and milk" and my app recognizes the food or identify them to see how many calories has each one from the following table:

```
Food         - cooked - Calories
Orange cake  - oven   -  200
Cow Milk     - raw    -  50
Sheep Milk   - raw    -  40
Orange       - juice  -  15
cereal bread - toast  -  10
bread        - toast  -  5
bacon        - toast  -  10
```

The solution I've made is a fulltext search for the whole string without doing any explode/implode functs. So the results I get are (by memory, so it's not accurate):

```
Fulltext rank  -  Food        - cooked  -  Cal
10,523634      -  bacon       - toast   -  10
5,2342342      -  sheep milk  - raw     -  40
5,2342342      -  cow milk    - raw     -  50
4,2342345      -  cereal bread- toast   -  10
3,2342344      -  orange cake - oven    - 200
2,2342342      -  orange      - juice   -  15


$query="
SELECT Food, cooked, 
MATCH ( Food, cooked)
AGAINST (  '$search' ) AS score 
FROM food_table 
WHERE
MATCH ( Food, cooked) 
AGAINST (  '$search' ) 
ORDER  BY Score 
DESC LIMIT 50";
```

I discovered that some scores where the same, sheep milk and cow milk so I added a new row in mysql called "milk - average" to be the first solution in fulltext and then I delete the rest of "same rank" solutions (I don't have more info from the user, so I just make an average of calories from different kind of milks)

But still, this is not very accurate, for example, with orange or others, fulltext give me a wrong first option, "orange cake - oven" when I wanted to have just "orange - juice" that matches better (at least it matches one column perfectly). But still, the results are giving me multiple options for the same input and doing a score discrimination is not enough to let the app "understand" that if it's entered once, it shouldn't have two results with the same input.

Just in case if I explained myself wrongly, the final results I want are:

```
input: 
an orange with toast bread and milk

Solution:
orange - juice - 15
bread  - toast - 5
milk   - average - 45 (this one, as said, is adding a new mysql row with the data)

Total: 65 calories
```

I don't want the code (if you have time is more than welcome) but the funcions I need to use for this purpose, or any other better way to do all of this, and I'll google it to understand.

The second part of the code is to identify the food even if they have any typo, for example oarnge. I think this is done with the Levenshtein distance not sure if I can apply the same solution for the whole need..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I never knew aliment was a proper English word meaning "food"...

Comment: It's more likely something that a translator spat out, so while valid, it's very much not used.

Comment: Well, I'm not a native english speaker, as you probably see, but as far as I know, food is very generic, and aliment refers to components, maybe is not used, but I think it's more accurate :)

Comment: Please add the query you use for the full-text search to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some options to solve your problem:

**Writing a natural language parser**
([NLP on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing))

You can use some parsing tools (just google *nlp php*) to map a phrase into a tree, do some part-of-speech tagging and so extract the words you need (maybe with their adjectives, so you can find if and how the food is cooked).
This way can be quite complex.

---

**Limit user input**

Only you know how your app is designed, but consider the possibility of changing the way the user can interact with it. You can *force* the user to click on a "add" button and select from a list of foods.

---

**Somwhere in the middle**

If you think that typing it's more natural and fast maybe you can find a compromise between the two above. Like asking the user to put commas between the "aliments" and/or implementing some sort of autocompletion.
In this case just some regular expressions can do the job.

---

For sure there are other paths to follow, like doing statistical nlp or using a dictionary to keep only useful words...

For what concerns typing errors: yes, Levenshtein distance is a widely used technique and you can use it (if you split the phrase in some manner so you have a string comparable to the Food column of your database).